# Merge dataframe using common keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've been trying to merge two dataframes so that:

- data with common keys will get updated => new column added with the additional value
- data with no common keys will be added as new rows (see sample below)

I have been testing with both `merge` and `concat` but I still did not find the right config for them I guess...

Runnable example: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zvfatnj9

```
# df A
  host  val1  val2
0   aa    11    44
1   bb    22    55
2   cc    33    66

# df B
  host  val1  val3
0   aa    11    77
1   bb    22    88
2   dd     0    99

# df Expected after merge
  host  val1  val2  val3
0   aa    11  44.0   77.0
1   bb    22  55.0   88.0
2   cc    33  66.0   NaN
3   dd     0   NaN  99.0
```

Comment: If row 1 of dfb was actually `bb    44    88`, what would your expected output be in row 1? Still `bb    22  55.0   88.0` or `bb    44 55.0   88.0`? Or would there be another row in the output with `bb 44 NaN 88`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I am actually merging using the two first columns as "primary keys", if matches, then a new column is added for the uncommon values, if doesn't match, then a new row is added instead. Check accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, using [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
cols = ['host', 'val1']
dfa.set_index(cols).join(dfb.set_index(cols), how='outer').reset_index()
```

---

Alternatively, using [`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first):

```
cols = ['host', 'val1']
dfa.set_index(cols).combine_first(dfb.set_index(cols)).reset_index()
```

---

Output:

```
  host  val1  val2  val3
0   aa    11  44.0  77.0
1   bb    22  55.0  88.0
2   cc    33  66.0   NaN
3   dd     0   NaN  99.0
```

Comment: Sorry I only revisited this task now. Only the 2nd worked, which is good enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, merging dataframes with common keys to update existing rows and add new rows can be tricky. While both merge and concat can be helpful, they require specific configurations to achieve the desired outcome.

Here's how you can achieve your desired result using both methods:

Method 1: Using merge with `how='outer' and custom logic

```
# Merge with how='outer' to include all rows
merged_df = df_A.merge(df_B, how='outer', on='host')

# Update existing rows with additional value
merged_df['val3'] = merged_df['val3'].fillna(np.nan)

# Add new columns with missing values for non-matching rows
merged_df['val2'] = merged_df['val2'].fillna(np.nan)

# Rearrange columns for better readability
merged_df = merged_df[['host', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']]
print(merged_df)
```

This approach uses merge with how='outer', ensuring all rows from both dataframes are included. Then, it fills missing values in val3 for rows from df_A and adds a new val2 column with np.nan for rows from df_B. Finally, it rearranges the columns for better readability.

Method 2: Using concat with custom indexing and handling

```
# Concatenate along axis=1 to join horizontally
merged_df = pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis=1, join='outer')

# Fill missing values with NaN
merged_df.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)

# Rename duplicate columns based on origin dataframe
merged_df.columns = [f'{col}_{origin}' if origin else col for col, origin in merged_df.columns]

# Rearrange columns for better readability
merged_df = merged_df[['host', *[col for col in merged_df.columns if col.endswith('_A')]]]
print(merged_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
merged_df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['host', 'val1'], how='outer')
```